# Flatten Hierarchy of variables

Tags: python

I have a Hierarchy of variables, something like

```
a.b.c.d1
a.b.c.d2
a.b.c.d3
a.b.c.d4
```

now I want to have them all into local namespace:

```
d1=2
d2=3
...
```

how can I accomplish that?

Comment: you probably want `c = a.b.c` to be a list or a dictionary e.g., if `c` is a list: `c[:1] = 2, 3` or if `c` is a dictionary: `c.update(d1=2, d2=3)` or `d.update(zip(names, values))`

Answer (score 2):

You actually can access all fields of an object in Python in a dict-like way, as long as it's a new-style class, i.e., the class inherits `object`, directly or indirectly.

Let's reduce the hierarchy to one level, like @unutbu proposed. Then a solution would be:

```
class A(object):
    d0 = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.d1 = 1
        self.d2 = 2
        self.d3 = 3
        self.d4 = 4

a = A()

for k in a.__dict__:
    print k, a.__dict__[k]
    globals()[k] = a.__dict__[k]

print d1, d2, d3, d4
print d0
```

This gives us as ouput:

```
d4 4
d2 2
d3 3
d1 1
1 2 3 4
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/../stackoverflow/14267654.py", line 24, in <module>
    print d0
NameError: name 'd0' is not defined
```

This means: **instance variables of new-style classes** can be accessed via the special `a.__dict__` field. Global variables can be set in the dictionary returned by `globals()`. Bring these together, and you have your solution.

Comment: I'm trying to make a recursive version of this, but I get a recursion depth exceeded error. Is there some steadfast way to tell the user-created variables from everything else?

Comment: I'm uncertain what you mean by "user-created" variables. And I also don't believe that no recursive version can be done. Maybe you have cyclic dependencies, like `b = d3` or something? There is also the function `sys.setrecursionlimit(n)` to increase the recursion limit. Maybe increasing the value a little bit might help.

Answer (score 1):

You could define

```
d1 = a.b.c.d1
d2 = a.b.c.d2
```

but assignments like

```
d1 = 2
```

would only affect the local variable `d1`, not `a.b.c.d1`.

If you want assignments to affect `a.b.c.d1`, use

```
c = a.b.c
c.d1 = 2
```

There is no way to do it with just a bare variable name like `d1`.

Comment: you know there are more then these two variables. I am searching for a way to do it not by hand! That would also have been my first guess.

Comment: @varantir The latter variant, defining another name for `c`, does that, is more explicit and less magic, and much simpler. It beats any hack for doing what you're asking for hands down.